# Move to a larger drive

Tags: hard-drive, user-account

My wife got me an external SSD for my bday. I'm on a 2013 Mac Pro, so my existing user folder is already on another external. I'd like to move to the new drive and use the old one for backups.

Given that the original user folder is not on a boot drive, can I simply copy the contents over? Is there anything else I need to do, like set the permission or anything?

Most guides say you should do this with Restore in DU, but the Restore... menu items is greyed out when I tried it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about if you can just copy over. Why is your user folder on a separate drive?? Anyway. I do have another suggestion. I got an ssd drive to use for my main drive, cause it's like ten times faster. I then ordered this thing that is basically the same shape as a cd Rom drive, but it holds a laptop hard drive. I removed the cd Rom drive and replaced it with that, which holds a terabyte drive. I partitioned it in half. 500gb is for my time machine backup, and the other 500gb is for extra storage. Or "external", without being external. I don't use DVD or cd's anymore, so it made sense to me. Good luck.